# Best eBook website for PhD students

Tags: phd, books

What's the best "bookmine" academic targeted website for PhD students to find references for their studies ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "bookmine" website?

Comment: i coined the word just now :D meaning a website where many books are offered to download in a PDF format :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have qualms about downloading from a site that has been [convicted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis#Legal_issues) for mass copyright infringement, then **Library Genesis** is probably the largest one. It is basically Scihub's sister site for books.

Their [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis) contains up-to-date links to access it (which may be blocked by some internet providers).

Check the legality of what you download. For instance, where I live you risk a 154€ fine for illicit downloads for personal use, without other aggravating factors. (I think at least -- IANAL.)

Answer (score 4):

In terms of how frequently it's given me the info I need, I think the champion has to be [Google Books](https://books.google.com/).  (A tip: Google Books will let you see more of the content of a book in its "preview" if you let it set cookies in your browser than if you don't.)  Honourable runners-up are [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/books), [Bibliothèque Nationale de France](https://www.bnf.fr/fr), and [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/).

Comment: OK but it looks to me like those cited are not necessarly academic targetted

Comment: @user1319236 They're not _exclusively_ academic-targeted, but they certainly include plenty of academic works.

Comment: no not what i am looking for.

Comment: @user1319236 This sounds like an XY Problem.  Perhaps if you edited your question to explain, more explicitly, what you are looking for, folk might be able to give you a more satisfactory answer.  For my money, this answer is quite comprehensive.