# How can I access an eBook or an article?

Tags: books, library

I come from a part of the world where neither I nor my institutional library can afford to access certain eBooks, not because of any imposed restriction but because of a lack of funds. It is quite frustrating at times.

How/who can I request for an eBook if that is not available with me or my library?

Comment: Some authors put the draft versions of their books in their websites. You may be lucky to catch the one you're looking for in this way.

Comment: `or an article?` -- Do you know about SciHub? Also, the preprints of many articles on Math, Physics (and many other subjects) are available on arxiv.org

Comment: Also see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158575/best-ebook-website-for-phd-students/158583#158583 (not all of the sites mentioned in the link are legal, though).

Comment: Are you a student? Professor?

Answer (score 1):

Libgen for textbooks, books, etc.

Scihub for research papers.

Comment: Note that both of them have been accused of copyright infringement. There are ethical considerations.

Comment: @Buffy The authors of articles within academic journals often receive no money for their work. I implore you to read sci-hubs website, as they talk about the ethical motivation behind the site.  https://sci-hub.se/medicine Unrealistically high paywalls are driven by publisher greed and prevent those who are less privileged (doctors in poorer countries, college students) from having access to valuable information.

Comment: What about textbook authors?  I suppose they don't deserve any royalties for their work?